# how to get file from ftp server and copy on own server

Tags: php, file, ftp

I want to get file from client server and copy them on my server , I have successfully connected to client server, my code is below.

```
// connect and login to FTP server
$ftp_server = "xx.xxx.xxx.xxx";
$ftp_username = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$ftp_userpass = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
 $ftp_conn = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("Could not connect to $ftp_server");
$login = ftp_login($ftp_conn, $ftp_username, $ftp_userpass);
echo "<pre>";
 print_r($login);
  echo "</pre>";
 // get the file list for /
 $filelist = ftp_rawlist($ftp_conn, "/");

// close connection
ftp_close($ftp_conn);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($filelist);
echo "</pre>";
// output $filelist
var_dump($filelist);
```

May anyone please advise how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I resolved this now all files will copy on your server. use **ftp_ssl_connect** if its secure

```
$ftp_server = "xx.xxx.xxx.xxx";
$ftp_username = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$ftp_userpass = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';

$ftp_conn = ftp_ssl_connect($ftp_server) or die("Could not connect to $ftp_server");
$login = ftp_login($ftp_conn, $ftp_username, $ftp_userpass);

ftp_pasv($ftp_conn,pasv);


$output_directory="files1/ftpgetfiles/137/";
// get the file list for /
$filelist = ftp_nlist($ftp_conn, "/");

foreach ($filelist as $key => $value) {
$fp = fopen($output_directory.$value,"w");
if(ftp_fget($ftp_conn, $fp, $value, FTP_BINARY))
{
    fclose($fp);
}
}

ftp_close($ftp_conn);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ftp_fget` function specified here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-fget.php

> (ftp_fget() retrieves remote_file from the FTP server, and writes it to the given file pointer.)

Here an example provided by the documentation:

```php
<?php

// path to remote file
$remote_file = 'somefile.txt';
$local_file = 'localfile.txt';

// open some file to write to
$handle = fopen($local_file, 'w');

// set up basic connection
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);

// login with username and password
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);

// try to download $remote_file and save it to $handle
if (ftp_fget($conn_id, $handle, $remote_file, FTP_ASCII, 0)) {
 echo "successfully written to $local_file\n";
} else {
 echo "There was a problem while downloading $remote_file to $local_file\n";
}

// close the connection and the file handler
ftp_close($conn_id);
fclose($handle);
?>
```